# Python: Shorter way of checking if a string equals two other strings

Tags: python

have just started learning python and this question came up to my mind
is there a shorter way to determine if a string equals 'something' or 'somethingelse'?

example:

```
input = raw_input("question?")

while input != 'n' and input != 'y':
    #ask question again
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check whether it is in a list or set.

```
input = raw_input("question?")

while input not in ['n', 'N']:
    #ask question again
```

If you are just trying to accept two cases though, you could also just call `lower` on the input.

```
while input.lower() != 'n':
    #ask question again
```

Comment: Or a set `{'n', 'N'}`

Comment: when I tried to use 'is not' it didn't work, why is that?

Comment: Never use `is` when checking string *value*. It checks the reference in memory @chemi

Comment: @Chemi, Please accept this answer if it resolves your question.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps unexpectedly, `'a' != input != 'b'` works. It resolves the same way as `('a' != input) and ('b' != input)`. You can do the same thing with `==`, or with `<`, `>`, etc. on numbers, as well.

Oh, but you have to be careful if you chain it longer than three things, or use multiple different comparison operators.

Comment: that helps alot, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it's a case issue, then you can:

```
while input.lower() != 'n'
```